# How to retrieve <textarea> value in Ruby Cucumber unit testing tool

Tags: textarea, cucumber

I am using the Cucumber unit test tool, and am trying to retrieve the value of a `textarea`, however I can't get it to work.

This is my code...

```
page.find(:xpath, "//div[@id='process']/table/tbody/tr/td/div/textarea").value
```

This is the error I'm getting...

```
Error: undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This URL listed below confirms that `value` is the correct method to retrieve the value:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp

Could someone please help me fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `nil` error indicates that you're not getting the textarea -- find is returning `nil`. Try a simpler xpath query, or referencing the textarea by name or id.

Comment: Thanks for the clue Don. The code worked after pointing to the right row. - Thanks again!!